# C# BitMap is unable to locate pixels

Tags: c#, bitmap

I've been working on a small application that basically runs off bitmap screenshot images. The bitmap is then detecting a certain pixel from a Resources.GrabPixel .bmp I loaded in. This method doesn't seem reliable in certain ways when many similar pixels are involved.

If I was to use this in a BlueStacks or Andy Emulator the return would be likely false. I've had instances were it would detect a game icon but for some odd reason a few days  later it would randomly stop detecting that same icon.

So is there a better method and approach I should be learning more towards? I'm not an expert in C# and any sample examples I could try and build off of would be great. I will list my code below if anyone thinks it can be improved by any means please share.

Goal: Detect certain pixel, while discarding unmatched pixels. A more accurate pixel reader.

The code listed below contains the bitmap and mouse_events.

```
public partial class frmMain : Form
{
    private const UInt32 MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = 0x0002;
    private const UInt32 MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = 0x0004;

    [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SetCursorPos")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    public static extern bool SetCursorPos([In] int X, [In] int Y);
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    static extern void mouse_event(uint dwFlags, uint dx, uint dy, uint dwData,
    int dwExtraInfo);

    public enum MouseEventFlags : uint
    {
        LEFTDOWN = 0x00000002,
        LEFTUP = 0x00000004,
        MIDDLEDOWN = 0x00000020,
        MIDDLEUP = 0x00000040,
        MOVE = 0x00000001,
        ABSOLUTE = 0x00008000,
        RIGHTDOWN = 0x00000008,
        RIGHTUP = 0x00000010,
        WHEEL = 0x00000800,
        XDOWN = 0x00000080,
        XUP = 0x00000100
    }
    public enum MouseEvents
    {
        MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = 0x02,
        MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = 0x04,
        MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN = 0x08,
        MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP = 0x10,
        MOUSEEVENTF_WHEEL = 0x0800,
    }

    public frmMain()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    // Loads the exe program
    private void btLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // takes a snapshot of the screen
        Bitmap bmpScreenshot = Screenshot();

        // makes the background of the form a screenshot of the screen
        ////this.BackgroundImage = bmpScreenshot;

        // find the Icon  and check if it exists
        Point location;
        bool success = FindBitmap(Properties.Resources.Programloader, bmpScreenshot, out location);

        // check if it found the bitmap
        if (success == false)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Couldn't locate Andy.exe!");
            return;
        }

        // move the mouse to Icon 
        Cursor.Position = location;

        // click
        MouseClick();
        MouseClick();
        if (success == true)
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
        }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Simulates a mouse click
    /// </summary>
    private void MouseClick()
    {
        mouse_event((uint)MouseEventFlags.LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        Thread.Sleep((new Random()).Next(20, 30));
        mouse_event((uint)MouseEventFlags.LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Takes a snapshot of the screen
    /// </summary>
    ///  <returns> A snapshot of the screen</return>
    private Bitmap Screenshot()
    {
        // this is where we will store a snapshot of the screen
        Bitmap bmpScreenshot = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);

        // creates a graphics object so we can draw the screen in the bitmap (bmpScreenshot)
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmpScreenshot);

        // copy from screen into the bitmap we created
        g.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size);

        // return the screenshot
        return bmpScreenshot;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Finds the location of a bit map within another bitmap and  returns if it was successfully found
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="bmpNeedle"> The image we want to find</param>
    /// <param name="bmpHaystack"> Where we want to search for the image</param>
    /// <param name="location"> Where we found the image</param>
    /// <returns> If the bmpNeedle was found successfully </returns>
    private bool FindBitmap(Bitmap bmpNeedle, Bitmap bmpHaystack, out Point location)
    {
        for (int outerX = 0; outerX < bmpHaystack.Width - bmpNeedle.Width; outerX++)
        {
            for (int outerY = 0; outerY < bmpHaystack.Height - bmpNeedle.Height; outerY++)
            {
                for (int innerX = 0; innerX < bmpNeedle.Width; innerX++)
                {
                    for (int innerY = 0; innerY < bmpNeedle.Height; innerY++)
                    {
                        Color cNeedle = bmpNeedle.GetPixel(innerX, innerY);
                        Color cHaystack = bmpHaystack.GetPixel(innerX + outerX, innerY + outerY);

                        if (cNeedle.R != cHaystack.R || cNeedle.G != cHaystack.G || cNeedle.B != cHaystack.B)
                        {
                            goto notFound;
                        }
                    }
                }
                location = new Point(outerX, outerY);
                return true;
            notFound:
                continue;
            }
        }
        location = Point.Empty;
        return false;
    }

    private void frmMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Start();
        timer1.Interval = 1;
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text = Cursor.Position.X.ToString() + ":" + Cursor.Position.Y.ToString();
    }

    private void button1_Click_3(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // takes a snapshot of the screen
        Bitmap bmpScreenshot = Screenshot();

        // makes the background of the form a screenshot of the screen
        //this.BackgroundImage = bmpScreenshot;

        // find the login button and check if it exists
        Point location;
        bool success = FindBitmap(Properties.Resources.Map, bmpScreenshot, out location);

        // check if it found the bitmap
        if (success == false)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Test Failed Badly.");
            return;
        }

        // move the mouse to login button
        Cursor.Position = location;

        // click
        MouseClick();
        MouseClick();
    }

    // Uses a Mouse_event to scroll (Right)
    private void button2_Click_2(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        uint X = (775);//set x position 
        uint Y = (340);//set y position 

        // Thread.Sleep(10000);
        mouse_event((uint)MouseEvents.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, X, Y, 0, 0);
        // Thread.Sleep(2000);
        SetCursorPos((int)X + 10, (int)Y + 10);
        // Thread.Sleep(2000);
        mouse_event((uint)MouseEvents.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, X + 15, Y + 15, 0, 0);

        uint A = (775);//set x position 
        uint B = (340);//set y position 
        mouse_event((uint)MouseEvents.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, A, B, 50, 50);

        SetCursorPos((int)A + 50, (int)B + 50);

        mouse_event((uint)MouseEvents.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, A, B, 50, 50);

        Cursor.Position = new Point(715, 218);
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        Cursor.Position = new Point(400, 218);
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        mouse_event((uint)MouseEvents.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, X + 15, Y + 15, 0, 0);
    }

    // Scans the sceen for a particular build(Farm,Sawmill,ect.)
    private void button6_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // takes a snapshot of the screen
        Bitmap bmpScreenshot = Screenshot();

        // makes the background of the form a screenshot of the screen
        //this.BackgroundImage = bmpScreenshot;

        // find the login button and check if it exists
        Point location;
        bool success = FindBitmap(Properties.Resources.HallofWar, bmpScreenshot, out location);

        // check if it found the bitmap
        if (success == false)
        {
            // MessageBox.Show("Test Failed Badly.");
            return;
        }

        // move the mouse to login button
        Cursor.Position = location;

        // click
        MouseClick();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand it right, you are trying to find out if a large bitmap contains a smaller bitmap. First off, let me say that `Bitmap.GetPixel` is very slow, so if you want to go this route, you'll be much better off if you copy the bitmap into an array first. You do that by calling `Bitmap.LockBits` and then you use `Marshal.Copy` to copy the raw data into an array. [This MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229672(v=vs.90).aspx) has an example.

If you don't want to reinvent the wheel, I would suggest using a library for this, for example [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/) (and its .NET port , [Emgu CV](http://www.emgu.com)). You can look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4569993/2d-subimage-detection-in-open-cv), which is about something very similar to what you are doing.

Finally, a word of warning: if I undestand it right, you are trying to find a program icon in a screenshot. However, depending on your DPI settings, resolution, transparency of the icon and its size, the icon you have may not be 100% pixel-by-pixel identical to the icon rendered on the screen.